# For Selenium Cucumber test in Java, where is the queue/list for test cases located?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am trying to make a way to manipulate the order of tests happening depending on currently running tests. I have taken quite a bit of time to search for how and where the order is held but have not found it. I was seeing if anyone could clue me into how this is done or where this is held?

I have searched through oracle documentation and cucumber documentation, but have not been able to understand how this part of it works.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber feature files are run in Alphabetical order by feature file name as default. But if you want to try something different by changing the order i.e. by changing the order of the scenarios `-- order = random` etc.

So if you want to run a certain scenario before another, make sure that the scenario description is Alphabetically before the other one.
If you want to prioritize `@Before` and `@After`, you can use `order = 0`, `order = 1` and so on.

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you for your answer. I was more looking for something like, if that is ran in random order, is there a list or anything that keeps up with the order that could possibly be manipulated at runtime.